# Firebase Push Notification - How to keep track of user FCM tokens?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is a general question around FCM tokens.  Currently in my react-native app, as soon as I have new token, I make an API call to link this token with a user ID.  And when this token is also refreshed, I make the same API call again.

We use those tokens to send 'Happy Birthday' push notifications and the likes.

I would like to know in the event that a user does not use the app, this token will get expired and we do not have a way to keep track of the token.   The birthday push notifs will still be sent to the old expired token.  How can we mitigate this? Any idea ?

I am actually looking for a way/strategy to still have the push notifications being delivered to the user even if they have not used the app for a while?  Do you think scheduled push notifications might work?

Answer (score 1):

When you send data to an expired token, you'll get a response indicating this. You can capture this response, and use that to remove the tokens from your database.

The [samples repo for Cloud Functions has a great example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) of this. Modified from there:

```
var response = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
// For each message check if there was an error.
const tokensToRemove = [];
response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
  const error = result.error;
  if (error) {
    // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
    if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
        error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
      tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know in the event that a user does not use the app,
>   this token will get expired and we do not have a way to keep track of
>   the token. The birthday push notifs will still be sent to the old
>   expired token. How can we mitigate this? Any idea?

In my case, I register for firebase token each time my front end application gets launched. Most of the time it sends the registration token which is already stored in my database. However, when a new firebase registration token is received in my server side, I store the new token and while sending the push notification, I send the notification to all available registration token that I have.

You cannot figure out if the user has stopped using your application until you get notified about launching your application by sending the firebase registration token to the server side application. Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually implemented you've done.  Is there another strategy that we can use to make sure that a specific user receives a 'Happy Birthday' message even if he stopped using the app a long time back?

Comment: umm ... I think no. The best way would be communicating with them via email or SMS.

Answer (score 0):

We shall drive campaigns that retain our clients.  All the above answers are right though.